# Connection to Postgres takes too long on some databases

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a Go application which uses a Postgres database (9.6). The funny thing is that on some databases establishing the connection takes longer.

There is one server the application is running on and a dedicated database server.

I have 2 databases:

1. very small, some kb of data. Connection takes ~1ms
2. Still very small, maybe 10 times as large as the first one. Connection takes ~20ms

This is reproductible all the time. I hunted it down to the `Dial` function in the `net` package.

Second funny thing: This happens only on a particular couple of servers which are in the same network as the database server.

I could not find anything about this problem. Does someone have information about this behavior?

Comment: "I could not find anything about this problem. Has someone information about this behavior?" Do you use a IP or a "domain name" (DNS) to connect to the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: omg Raymond. That was the actual difference. The host for the first database was specified with an IP, the second one with a domain :facepalm:

thanks alot!

Comment: "That was the actual difference. The host for the first database was specified with an IP, the second one with a domain" Yea using DNS is slower then connecting to the IP directly.. Or you need to configure DNS to use a longer TTL then if should be cached on the OS.